# handle incrementing number of array ID in duplicated form field set (regex)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, arrays, forms

I need to duplicate rows of a form ( in a table )

See jsbin here : http://jsbin.com/ExiRAMa/1/edit

The markup :

```
<div id="o99_the_work">
  <table><tbody>
  <tr>
                <!--    THE ORDER -->
<td>X</td>
<td class="small-text"><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap submitted-file"><input type="file" name="submitted-file" value="1" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-file" id="submitted-file-1"></span></td>
<td><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap number-of-copies"><input type="text" name="number-of-copies" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text small-text" id="number-of-copies-1"></span></td>
<td><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap checkbox-copy-type"><span class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-checkbox" id="copy-type-1"><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-copy-type[]" value="color">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">color</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-copy-type[]" value="bw">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">bw</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-copy-type[]" value="transperant">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">transperant</span></span><span class="wpcf7-list-item"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-copy-type[]" value="pergament">&nbsp;<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">pergament</span></span></span></span></td>
<td><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap submitted-remarks"><input type="text" name="submitted-remarks" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" id="submitted-remarks-1"></span> </td>
    </tr></tbody></table>
    <button id="add_row">Add new</button>
</div>
```

The JS :

```
jQuery("#add_row").click(function() {
    var row = jQuery("#k99_the_work tbody > tr:last"),
        newRow = row.clone(true);

    newRow.find("input[type=text],input[type=file]").each(function() {
        var num = +(this.id.match(/\d+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
        this.id = this.id.replace(/\d+$/, "") + num;
        this.name = this.id;
    });

    newRow.insertAfter(row);
    return false;
});
```

As you can see from the bin, the scripts works fine on input=text and it is incrementing both the name and ID - but my  problem is how to deal with the checkboxes .
I need to increment the name, ID etc , while keeping it seperate arrays `checkbox-copy-type[]` .
Meaning , after duplication i need `checkbox-copy-type-1[]`, `checkbox-copy-type-2[]` etc

I am by no means a regex person, but I tried adding :

```
newRow.find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    var num = +(this.id.match(/checkbox-copy-type/) || [0])[0] + 1;
    //      this.id = this.name.replace(/\[]/, "vv") + num;
    this.id = this.name.replace(/\[]/, "") + num;// take off the brackets
    this.id = this.name + "[]" ;// add the brackets again
    this.name = this.id;
});
```

But all I get when I try this is another set of brackets e.g. `checkbox-copy-type[][]` ,`checkbox-copy-type[][][]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it like so :

```
newRow.find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function() {

var parentid = jQuery(this).parent().parent();
    var num = +(this.id.match(/checkbox-copy-type+$/) || [0])[0] + 1;
  this.id = this.name.replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; });
    this.name = this.id;
    parentid.attr("id",parentid.attr("id").replace(/\d+/, function(val) { return parseInt(val)+1; }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the item in the data portion of html (if its unique for each tr/checkbox) retrieve it that way and then increment it, then add the brackets in.

**HTML**

```
 <tr data-name="myName"></tr>
```

**javascript**

```
newRow.find("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(x, item) {
    var name = $(item).data('name'); //this give you the name if it unique
    var newName = name + x + '[]' // this give final result
});
```

Comment: Thanks , I do believe this can be a good method. Unfortunatly , the fields are added with another scipt , and I can not use data-type.. What I do not understand is why my regex not working ...